# No compatible provider for the version of entity framework

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6

I have an empty project, that is created with VS2013 and .net 4.5.1.

I have installed the version 1.0.93.0 that install the designer components on visual studio. I don't use the last version 1.0.94.0 because there is a problem that does not allow me to create a new connection in the wizard that create the model edmx, because the provider is not available.

Well, after installing the designer components, I go to the NuGet console manager and I install the last version of the SQLite, version 1.0.94.0. This install five packages and update my config file to this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <!--
        NOTE: The extra "remove" element below is to prevent the design-time
              support components within EF6 from selecting the legacy ADO.NET
              provider for SQLite (i.e. the one without any EF6 support).  It
              appears to only consider the first ADO.NET provider in the list
              within the resulting "app.config" or "web.config" file.
    -->
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Also add the needed references, such as EF 6.0 dll, SQLite.dll, SQLite.EF6.dll and SQLite.Linq.dll.

Now I try to create my edmx model, I can create a new connection to my SQLite database and then, in the next step, I get a message that says that I have the last version of EF, but I don't have a compatible provider.

I tr to clean the app.config and use this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.94.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="northwindEFEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NorthwindModel.EF6.2013.csdl|res://*/NorthwindModel.EF6.2013.ssdl|res://*/NorthwindModel.EF6.2013.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\northwindEF.db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.94.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

This configuration is from the zip file that I can download form the web of SQLite, the file sqlite-netFx451-static-binary-bundle-x64-2013-1.0.94.0.zip, that has a test program, for EF and EF6, and both of them works. But with this configuration does not work.

So I Would like to know how can I create a edmx model with SQLite with EF6. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you so much.